# how to fill two dimensional array(as a pointer) in a function?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, pointers

I declared this in the main :

```
char** board;
int N;
  .
  .
  .
  fill_Board(board, N);
```

then I scanf the number N and using malloc I did dynamic allocation for the char** board like that :

```
  void creat_board(char*** board,int N)
  {
   int i=0;
    (*board)=(char**)malloc(N*sizeof(char*)); 
     if (board==NULL)
     {
       printf("malloc failed!\n");
       exit(1);
     }
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
       {
        (*board)[i]=(char*)malloc(N*sizeof(char)); /*add the 
        if((*board)[i]==NULL)
       {
         printf("malloc failed!\n");
         exit(1);
       }
     }
 }
```

I want now to fill the board and to print it but its not working ..here is what I tried to fill:

```
Void fill_Board(char** board,int N)
  {
    int i=0,j=0;
    
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
           for(j=0;j<N;j++)
           {
            board[i][j]='S';  
            }                  
         }
     }
```

when I tried to print it the values in the array (board) didnt change at all .why it that happening??

Comment: How do we know your allocation code isn't wrong? Or your print code? Or anything in between? Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Show how you allocate space for `board` and how you display the contents.  Your code should be in the form of a [mcve] so that others can run your code and see the same results you do.

Comment: i just added the dynamic allocation

Comment: @nina97 When you allocate the so-called two-dimensional array in a function then declare its parameter with three stars.:)

Comment: I didnt understand

Comment: @nina97 The condition in the if statement if (board==NULL) is incorrect. You need to write if (*board==NULL)

Comment: @nina97 As it was already said provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ok I changed it but that didnt help me with changing the values of the array to 'S'

Answer (score 0):

use pointer to array:

```
void fill_Board(size_t N, char (*board)[N][N])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            (*board)[i][j]='S';  
        }                  
    }
}
```

or more simple:

```
void fill_Board(size_t N, char board[N][N])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            board[i][j]='S';  
        }                  
    }
}
```

to dynamically allocate memory:

```
void *create_Board(size_t N)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(char[N][N]));
}
```

Comment: isnt char** board is equal to board[N][N] ??

Comment: @nina97 No, they are two different types.

Comment: @nina97 You were already said to provide a reproducible complete example. What is the problem?

Comment: so in the **board I cant change the values right ?

Comment: its very long I already provided the dynamic allocation and the fill_board function ..what do u need more

Comment: @nina97 instead of pointer to pointer use dynamically allocated 2D array. See amended answer